# JComboBox not displaying array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

Trying to pass an array into my JComboBox, but the combo box displays empty.
Here's GUI.java

```
package prototype;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.awt.Insets;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        startUp();
        loadCarList();
        loadRegPlateArray();
    }
    
    public static void startUp()
    {
        try {
            File file = new File("Car.csv");
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
                pw.println("regPlate,price,make,model,fType,colour,mileage,prevOwners,mpg,0to60,bhp,maxSpeed,feature1,feature2,feature3,feature4,sold,boughtFor,profit");
                pw.close();
                System.out.println("Data loaded successfully!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Data loaded successfully!");
            }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    
    public static void loadCarList()
    {
        String currentLine = "";
        String[] linearray;
                
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Car.csv")))
        {
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                linearray = currentLine.split(",");
                Car tempcar = new Car(
                                    linearray[0], Double.parseDouble(linearray[1]), linearray[2], linearray[3], linearray[4], linearray[5], Integer.parseInt(linearray[6]),
                                    Integer.parseInt(linearray[7]), Double.parseDouble(linearray[8]), Double.parseDouble(linearray[9]), Integer.parseInt(linearray[10]),
                                    Integer.parseInt(linearray[11]), linearray[12], linearray[13], linearray[14], linearray[15], Boolean.parseBoolean(linearray[16]),
                                    Double.parseDouble(linearray[17]), Double.parseDouble(linearray[18]));
                CarList.carArray.add(tempcar);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
            
    public static void loadRegPlateArray()
    {
        CarList cl = new CarList();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < CarList.carArray.size(); i++)
        {
            cl.regArray[i] = CarList.carArray.get(i).regPlate;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUI() {
        CarList cl = new CarList();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(500, 200, 1000, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 124, 123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 275, 189, 7, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 155, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);
        
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(cl.regArray));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_comboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);
    }
}
```

Here's Car.java

```
package prototype;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Car {
    public String regPlate;
    public double price;
    public String make;
    public String model;
    public String fType;
    public String colour;
    public int mileage;
    public int prevOwners;
    public double mpg;
    public double noughttosixty;
    public int bhp;
    public int maxSpeed;
    public String feature1;
    public String feature2;
    public String feature3;
    public String feature4;
    public boolean sold;
    public double boughtFor;
    public double profit;
    
    public String[] regPlates;
    public String allRegPlates;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public List<String[]> line = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String lines = "";
    
    public String thisLine;
    
    public Car(String cregPlate, double cprice, String cmake, String cmodel, String cfType,
            String ccolour, int cmileage, int cprevOwners, double cmpg, double cnoughttosixty, int cbhp, int cmaxSpeed,
            String cfeature1, String cfeature2, String cfeature3, String cfeature4, boolean csold, double cboughtFor, double cprofit)
    {
        this.regPlate = cregPlate;
        this.price = cprice;
        this.make = cmake;
        this.model = cmodel;
        this.fType = cfType;
        this.colour = ccolour;
        this.mileage = cmileage;
        this.prevOwners = cprevOwners;
        this.mpg = cmpg;
        this.noughttosixty = cnoughttosixty;
        this.bhp = cbhp;
        this.maxSpeed = cmaxSpeed;
        this.feature1 = cfeature1;
        this.feature2 = cfeature2;
        this.feature3 = cfeature3;
        this.feature4 = cfeature4;
        this.sold = csold;
        this.boughtFor = cboughtFor;
        this.profit = cprofit;
    }
}
```

Here's CarList.java

```
package prototype;

import java.util.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CarList {
    static ArrayList<Car> carArray = new ArrayList<Car>();
    String[] regArray = new String[carArray.size()];
}
```

Here's my CSV file.
[image: Cars.csv]

When I test `regArray` and print it to the CLI, it shows a list of arrays at it should. However, when I send it to the `JComboBox`, it doesn't work.
Not sure what I need to do here.

Comment: _I have a CSV_ I assume you mean that you have a CSV file. I don't see, in your code, that you are reading this file.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the CSV file. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating CarList twice. Therefore populating it in loadRegPlateArray() won't matter.

Just create a global CarList cl = new CarList(); and don't create it inside both methods.

Answer (score 1):

Method `startup()` creates an empty file if file `Car.csv` does not exist. When the file does not exist, you create it and write invalid data to it. I think you should delete that method.

Method `loadCarList()` should be called before you call the constructor of class `GUI`. Here is a line from that constructor

```java
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(cl.regArray));
```

When this line is executed, `cl.regArray` is empty because you have not yet called method `loadCarList()`. But there is another problem. In the constructor of class `GUI` you create a new instance of class `CarList` which is separate from the instance that you created in method `loadCarList()`, so even if you call `loadCarList()` before you call `GUI` class constructor, your `ComboBoxModel` will still be empty. In order to keep the changes in your existing code to a minimum, you should call method `loadRegPlateArray()` from within the `GUI` class constructor and you should also add a parameter to that method so that it loads the array of the `CarList` instance that you create in `GUI` class constructor. But there is another problem in method `loadRegPlateArray()`. When you create an instance of class `CarList`, you set the size of `regArray` to be the size of `carArray` so you need to initialize `carArray` before you call `CarList` constructor so method `loadCarList()` must be the first method called from method `main()`.

So, to summarize, here is a list of the changes that need to be made. Note that these changes will just make sure that your `JComboBox` will display data.

1. Make sure file `Car.csv` exists and contains data before you run your application.
2. The first thing that your application should do is load the data from file `Car.csv`
3. After loading the data, call constructor of class `GUI`
4. First thing to do in that constructor is create an instance of `CarList` and initialize `regArray`
5. Create and display your GUI.

The only class I changed was `GUI`. Here is the code of that class with my changes.

```java
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadCarList();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void loadCarList() {
        String currentLine = "";
        String[] linearray;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Car.csv"))) {
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                linearray = currentLine.split(",");
                Car tempcar = new Car(linearray[0],
                                      Double.parseDouble(linearray[1]),
                                      linearray[2],
                                      linearray[3],
                                      linearray[4],
                                      linearray[5],
                                      Integer.parseInt(linearray[6]),
                                      Integer.parseInt(linearray[7]),
                                      Double.parseDouble(linearray[8]),
                                      Double.parseDouble(linearray[9]),
                                      Integer.parseInt(linearray[10]),
                                      Integer.parseInt(linearray[11]),
                                      linearray[12],
                                      linearray[13],
                                      linearray[14],
                                      linearray[15],
                                      Boolean.parseBoolean(linearray[16]),
                                      Double.parseDouble(linearray[17]),
                                      Double.parseDouble(linearray[18]));
                CarList.carArray.add(tempcar);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void loadRegPlateArray(CarList cl) {
        for (int i = 0; i < CarList.carArray.size(); i++) {
            cl.regArray[i] = CarList.carArray.get(i).regPlate;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUI() {
        CarList cl = new CarList();
        loadRegPlateArray(cl);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(500, 200, 1000, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 124, 123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 275, 189, 7, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 155, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(cl.regArray));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_comboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

carArray.size() is zero , so when you instanciate regArray like you do:

> String[] regArray = new String[carArray.size()];

regArray here is becoming an array of size zero....

also this:

```
CarList.carArray.size()
```

is normally zero too..double check these two.

Finally,  this code is very low quality and you should respect the OOP notions especially when coding in Java otherwise you'll lose a lot of time and effort rewriting your code.

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure if this helps, but I've updated my question to show the full code.
Am i declaring the arrays of size zero still?
Thank you!
barakallahu feek